# ReactJS Ionic cannot remove padding from Grid Col element

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I'm using React-Ionic and I am not able to reduce the top/bottom padding from the `Col` element of my `Grid`. 
This is the code I'm using

```
       <IonGrid fixed={true} >
          <IonRow >
            {
              categories.map(l => {
                return (
                  <IonCol key={l.name} size="6" size-md >
                    <IonCard style={{ backgroundColor: '#444' }}>
                      <IonCardHeader >
                        <IonIcon style={{ display: 'flex', fontSize: '30px', marginBottom: 10 }} icon={l.icon} />
                        <IonCardTitle style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>{l.name}</IonCardTitle>
                      </IonCardHeader>
                    </IonCard>
                  </IonCol>
                )
              })
            }
          </IonRow>
        </IonGrid>
```

and below you can see the result, but I wanted to have vertically closer the cards.
I also tried to change the code to

```
<IonCard style={{ backgroundColor: '#444', paddingTop:0, paddingBottom:0 }}>
```

without results. 
Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a combination of `padding` and `margin`, i reduced it to zero so you can adjust accordingly

```
<IonCol key={l} size="6" size-md  style={{ padding : 0}}>
  <IonCard style={{ backgroundColor: '#444', padding :0 , margin :0 }}>
    <IonCardHeader >
      <IonIcon style={{ display: 'flex', fontSize: '30px', marginBottom: 10 }} icon={homeOutline} />
      <IonCardTitle style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>{l + " THIS IS TITLE"}</IonCardTitle>
    </IonCardHeader>
  </IonCard>
</IonCol>
```

[image]